# MS Test Manager - Outputting a result when a test passes

Tags: unit-testing, microsoft-test-manager, vs-unit-testing-framework

When writing unit tests, and running them in MTM, I'd really like to be able to include some textual data for passing tests.

[image]

For example, if the test passes it would be great if in the Notes field I could put the customer id of the customer we have created, so it can be verified manually if needs be.

In the unit test I could simply do an Assert.Inconclusive and pass it via the Error message field, but that would muddy the results, as would an Assert.Fail.

Any ideas how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I found this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulking/archive/2011/10/12/using-the-tfs-object-model-to-populate-test-details.aspx

It's a bit of a clunky solution, but it does work. If anyone has a better (read: simpler) solution, please post it.